# Python Pandas: Create a nested function to create new cols in final output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to create a function to trigger inner nested function in order to create my desired output.
I wish to output a new dataframe with new columns based on different conditions.

snippet of code:

```
    def func1(df):
      alist = []
      error ={}
      for i in df.index:
          if pd.isna([df.at[i, "col_name"]) == True:
          alist.append[i]
          df[alist,'new_col'] = "some msg" 
     return df             

    def func2(df):
      alist = []
      error ={}
      for i in df.index:
          if pd.isna([df.at[i, "other_col_name"]) == True and pd.isna([df.at[i, "other_col_name2"]== False:
          alist.append[i]
          df[alist,'new_col2'] = "some msg2" 

       return df

    def func3(df):
      func1(df)
      func2(df)
      
    return df ( The output with the new added columns new_col1 and new_col2)
```

Thanks for the help !

I am also receiving lots of settingwithcopywarning:, I am hoping there is a better way to  create my
new columns too

Comment: please post your data (not an image) and what the expected final df should look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the new column weirdly

```
df[alist, 'new_col'] = 'some_msg'
```

Just set it directly

```
    def func1(df):
      alist = []
      error ={}
      for i in df.index:
          if pd.isna([df.at[i, "col_name"]) == True:
          alist.append[i]
          df['new_col'] = i 
     return df
```

Comment: Hi  james, i am trying to add a new column but only certain rows should have new msg. Hence the syntax was writren in that way